# Trigger a sound based on a script function in Google Sheets via a sidebar add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The post below outlines how to set up the sidebar which can play a sound on Google Sheets

[How can I play a sound as part of a triggered function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787307/how-can-i-play-a-sound-as-part-of-a-triggered-function)

It works, sidebar opens up with the sheet and makes the sound when I press the play button.

However I haven't been able to trigger a play action from a function on a script.

I need a trigger function like this one -

```
function playme() {
('#player.play')
}
```

Update (Solved) -

There's no need to use IFRAME sandbox for my requirement, complicates the matters unnecessarily.

The post below provides an elegant solution (without the use of IFRAME), where the sidebar script runs a simple poll for the selected range and triggers a sound if there's change compared to previous poll values.

[Google Script: Play Sound when a specific cell change the Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881605/google-script-play-sound-when-a-specific-cell-change-the-value)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the player object using `document.getElementById`, then you can call the functions to control the [player](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp).

```
<script>
  function play() {
    var player = document.getElementById("player");

    player.play();
  }
</script>
```

To get the function to run you need to call the play() function. An easy way to do this would be to add a button  to the html part of the code:

```
<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="play();"/>
```

Comment: thanks, I've added document.getElementById part but still unable to trigger a play action. Something is wrong - updated the post with the entire code.

Comment: Added <input type="button" value="Play" onclick="play();"/>  part, a button popped up on the sidebar, but it doesn't do anything when I click. I think "player.play();" in "function play()" doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me so you need to debug:  Is the event is being triggered?  Does document.getElementById() return null?  Is there an error in the console when player.play() is called? If you right-click on the sidebar and choose "inspect element" you will be brought to the developer tools - there is a lot going on there, start with the console window and see if there are any obvious error messages.

Comment: How do you trigger the play from the app script not a button that the user has to click